# calculating total area of multiple polygons in qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, area

I wish to know the total area of all polygons within a shapefile layer.
So far I have added a new column to the attribute table that shows me the individual area of the polygons.I tried to copy the column out of attribute table to do it in calc, but that did not work. How can i calculate the total area of all polygons ?